# python django rest-auth: no password set in admin panel using custom RegisterSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using rest-auth. I have create an custom RegisterSerializer and a custom user model. Registration is working properly but when I check password of user in admin panel it shows 'no password set' and when try to login it is showing

{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}

## models.py

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self,username, email, password, is_staff,is_admin, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username')

        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_active=True,
            is_admin=is_admin,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self,username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user( username, email, password, False, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_staff(self,username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user( username,email, password,  True, False, False, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_admin(self,username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user( username,email, password,  True, True, False, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user( username,email, password,  True, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = CharField(_('username'), max_length=100,unique=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    email = EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = BooleanField(default=False)                                                                                                                                                    
    is_active = BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_joined = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True
```

## serializer.py

I had removed one password field

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=get_username_max_length(),
        min_length=allauth_settings.USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH,
        required=allauth_settings.USERNAME_REQUIRED
    )
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)


    def validate_username(self, username):
        username = get_adapter().clean_username(username)
        return username

    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email and email_address_exists(email):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    _("A user is already registered with this e-mail address."))
        return email

    def validate_password(self, password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def custom_signup(self, request, user):
        pass

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'password': self.validated_data.get('password', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', '')
        }

    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        self.custom_signup(request, user)
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])
        return user
```

## settings.py

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ### rest ###
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',

    ### MyAPP ###
    'accounts'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'reality.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'reality.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


######################## rest settings ########################
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
SITE_ID = 1
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'accounts.api.serializers.RegisterSerializer',
}
```

## admin.py

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    #password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( 'email','username','password')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        # password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        # if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        #     raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','username','password', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        # password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        # if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        #     raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('username','email' )
    list_filter = ('is_staff','is_admin','is_superuser')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('username',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff','is_admin','is_superuser')}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password'),
        }),
    )
    search_fields = ('username',)
    ordering = ('-username',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)


# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

**what is wrong in this code?** Please tell.

**ThankYou**.